# Regex for Cyrillic and international characters

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex listed below is fulfilling almost all my requirements, there is only one missing:

*It must have at least 3 compulsory alpha-numeric characters excluding special character*.

```
/^(?!(?:[ \d]+|[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ ]+)$)(?!(.)\1+$)(?!.*([a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ0-9])\2{3})(?!.*[^a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ0-9\n]{2})(?=(?:[^a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ0-9\n]*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ0-9]){3})(?!.*[Pp]+(OST|ost)*\.*\s*[Oo0]*(FFICE|ffice)*\.*\s*[Bb]*\.*\s*[Oo0]*\.*\s*[Xx].*)[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ0-9\ *"(:,\/.\\;&)\[\]_+#'-]{3,40}$/
```

The following are my acceptance criteria:

1. Minimum of 3 characters (includes alphabets and numbers, not
   including special Characters)
2. It must have at least 3 compulsory alpha-numeric characters excluding
   special characters - not working yet
3. All alphabets cannot be the same in a standalone word. However, if
   they are a part of the word, we will allow the same. E.g.
   `AAA` is not allowed but `Haaadoop` is allowed
4. Consecutive alphabets less than or equal to 3 are allowed in a word.
   E.g. `Haaadoop` is allowed but `Haaaadoop` is not allowed.
5. Three or more consecutive Standalone alphabets are not allowed.
   E.g. `AA` is allowed but `AAA` is not allowed.
6. All numbers can be the same. E.g. `111` or `111111` is allowed
7. More than 1 consecutive special character (in a word or Standalone) is not allowed. E.g. `A-B` is allowed, `A- -B` or `A-&B` is not allowed
8. Allow the following special characters: `#&()_+[]:;',/.-"*`
9. Consecutive dashes, apostrophes are not allowed in any part of the
   string
10. It should accept these international and cyrilic characters as well: `ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßŸàáâãäåæçАаБбВвГгДдЕеЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯяèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ`
11. These international and cyrilic characters should be accepted in
    starting of the word or in between of the words or in the end of the
    word

The following test cases should be accepted

- `Haaadoop 123`
- `A-B 123`
- `123 âãäåæçèéêëìíî`
- `нОоСсТт 123`
- `123 нОоСсТт`
- `нОр123Тт`
- `123 Haaadoop`
- `123 A-B`
- `âãäåæçèéêëìíî 123`
- `âãäåæ123çèéêëìíî`
- `111 asdasdbhb`
- `1111 asdwebqfbwejbf`
- `âãäåæçèéêëìíî 123`
- `1111111111 adfsdfdsf`

The following test cases should be rejected:

- `Haaaaadoop 123`
- `A- -B 123`
- `A-&B123`
- `AAA`
- `abcd`
- `123`
- `123 Haaaaadoop`
- `123 A- -B`
- `2 a`

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: All characters are "international."

Comment: Seems you need to see [How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)

Comment: *"It Must have at least 3 compulsory alpha-numeric characters excluding special character"* - add a positive lookahead after `^`: `(?=(?:[^alphanumeric]*[alphanumeric]){3})` where you need to replace *alphanumeric* with  the alnum pattern you have (including the "international" chars).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it didnt worked

Comment: When you say something does not work, we do not know WHAT and HOW that something did not work. What happened and what you tried? Update the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder every thing is getting accepted only 1111111111 adfsdfdsf is not being accepted

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the last acceptance criteria is not being accepted only else everything is working as expected

Comment: @PratyakshChaudhary I tried to bring your question in shape. Feel free to rollback if you don't like or if I did a mistake while doing so.

Comment: Yes a Regexpr can do that. No it's not the best way to do it. **You should test each condition separately, so your code will be easier to maintain**: if one condition changes, it will be easier to change it.

Answer (score 0):

*Note 1: the criteria renumbered for reference*

*Note 2: I will use PCRE syntax initially for its support of `x` modifier. The JavaScript-flavoured regex will come at the end of the post.*

Written almost literally your criteria may be represented as follows (criteria references in comments):

```
^
(?=(?:.*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ0-9]){3,})  # 1 & 2
(?!.*\b([a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ])\1+\b)    # 3
(?!.*  ([a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ])\2{3,})   # 4
(?!     [a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ]{3,}$)     # 5
(?=([0-9])\3+$|(?!\d+$))                        # 6 + implied by the test data "no number
                                                # alone on a string unless all digits are
                                                # the same" rule
(?!.*[\ *"(:,\/.\\;&)\[\]_+#'-]{2,})            # 7
[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ0-9\ *"(:,\/.\\;&)\[\]_+#'-]{3,40}$
```

The regex does not include the "post office" restriction appearing in the original expression since it's missing in the criteria list but this easily can be added.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/DOM8C0/1

And the JavaScript version:

```
^(?=(?:.*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ0-9]){3,})(?!.*\b([a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ])\1+\b)(?!.*([a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ])\2{3,})(?![a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ]{3,}$)(?=([0-9])\3+$|(?!\d+$))(?!.*[\ *"(:,\/.\\;&)\[\]_+#'-]{2,})[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ0-9\ *"(:,\/.\\;&)\[\]_+#'-]{3,40}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8eCYCy/1

Comment: Acceptance criteria is incorrrect.As it is an alphanumeric field so it should accept both numbers and alphabets.All the numbers can be same but it should be alphanumeric and Consecutive alphabets less than or equal to 3 are allowed in a word but not more than that.E.g. Haaadoop is allowed but Haaaadoop is not allowed.